# My changes caused this error. Property 'children' of type 'TreeNode<T>[] | null | undefined' is not assignable to string index type 'T'

Tags: typescript

The previous interface is no problem

```
interface TreeNode<T> {
    id: T;
    children?: Array<TreeNode<T>> | null;
}
```

I make id variable

```
interface TreeNode<T> {
    [id: string]: T;
    children?: Array<TreeNode<T>> | null;
}
```

Prompt ts error
Property 'children' of type 'TreeNode[] | null | undefined' is not assignable to string index type 'T'.

How can i fix it？

Comment: You're mentioning the interface it'll just provide the type as like string we do in classes .. so you have to define the property or variable as null or an array

Comment: that's why it's Complaining on string ... and also it's in interface id:T you've to clearify the type not a value in the interface

Comment: `[id: string]: T;` means that any string key in `TreeNode` should be a `T`

Answer (score 0):

Using `[id: string]: TreeNode<T>` caused a compilation error because `TreeNode<T>` has a `children` property which is not of type `TreeNode<T>`.

Here is a way to see the problem,. if you could compile it what would have been the return type of `foo()`?

```
  function foo(t: TreeNode<Date>) {
    return t['children']
  }
```

according to `[id: string]: TreeNode<T>` the return type is `TreeNode<T>` which in our case is `TreeNode<Date>`. but according to `children?: Array<TreeNode<T>> | null;` the return type is `Array<TreeNode<Date>> | null`. Due to this conflict the compiler does not let you compile this interface.

Note that the following does work:

```
interface TreeNode<T> {
  [id: number]: TreeNode<T>;
  children?: Array<TreeNode<T>> | null;
}
```